# How to add prefix and remove double quotes from the value in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a value called `"FooBar"`. I want to replace this text with the quotes to `Enr::Rds::FooBar` without quotes.

### Update:

For example, `@question.answer_model` gives the value `"FooBar"` (with the quotes)

I am a newbie and somebody please refer me how would i start to know about regex? What is the best way to practice in online?

Comment: try this "Enr::Rds::#{string.gsub('"', '')}"

Comment: its displays like Enr::Rds::foobar. I want Enr::Rds::FooBar and without the quotes

Comment: if you're getting `Enr::Rds::foobar`, that means your string is `foobar` and not `FooBar`

Comment: Where are you seeing the double quotes? When `@question.answer_model` is called from the console, it does show the double quotes. If the same is called from the view, or writing to a file, the double quotes won't show.

Comment: @jvnill still i got the answer like this.. `<dd>undefined method find&#x27; for &quot;Enr::Rds::FlatFloorLevel&quot;:String</dd>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to: a) drop the quotes and b) prepend `FooBar` with `Enr::Rds::`, I would suggest you preform exactly what is intended, literally:

```
'"FooBar"'.delete('"').gsub(/\A/, "Enr::Rds::")
# => "Enr::Rds::FooBar"
```

Comment: still i got with quotes.. `<dd>undefined method find&#x27; for &quot;Enr::Rds::FlatFloorLevel&quot;:String</dd>`

Comment: Would you please give a notice _where_ you get this _from_? I see no `<dd>` etc mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to convert a string to a constant.  try the following

```
"Enr::Rds::#{@question.answer_model.gsub('"', '')}".constantize.find(...)
```